# How to launch an SSRS report in a browser window?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am new to SSRS and I have built many reports using SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS).  A common complaint from the business users is that they don't want to navigate to the Report Manager (or a SharePoint document library) in order to run their reports.  Ideally they would like to launch a report from within the application by clicking a button and redirect to web browser.  Can you provide an example of how to do this?

Comment: Could you not just provide your business user an embedded web link to the SSRS report from whatever from end for the button you provide?

Comment: as long as the user not direct to the report manager and able to access the reports by url is fine.

Comment: Right ok, so have you thought of what type of interface you're going to provide your business user then if a URL is acceptable? Have you attempted to implement any solution and you're stuck on how to go to the next step or have you hoped for a full solution to your problem will be provided via StackOverflow?

Comment: Copy and email the relevant report URLs from SSRS to the relevant users. Suggest they save them as favourites in their favourite browser?

Comment: try sth like IIS & config manager and really don't know what to do, but as i said I'm new to this area. I don't want to ask anyone provide full solution to me, some tips or guideline will be great. Interface will be simple and easy, click url and display the report is fine.

Comment: @DaleBurrell was thinking like this. but out of the vm, i cant access the url. only access within local machine.

Comment: Why not create a report suite / menu / dashboard within RS? Create a report, add report links and descriptions and let the users launch their reports from that menu.

Comment: @JonTout do you mind give me some more information? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done due to the limitations I face at work.

Add a matrix or table, doesn't necessarily need a dataset, but adding one won't do any harm. The Report is linked as per the left hand column, it's the report name in the data field with a text box action, **Go To URL** which links to whichever report you want to run. A simple notes field highlighting what the report does and the URL of this report is what's run by each department.

[image]